# Netbeans Building Issues for C++

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors

I'm using the MinGW complier/make/etc files but whenever I try to run my code it spits this back out to me:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Geneva/workspace/C++ Through Game Programming'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/c___through_game_programming.exe
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Geneva/workspace/C++ Through Game Programming'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/c___through_game_programming build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/diceroll.o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Geneva\workspace\C++ Through Game Programming/main.cpp:35: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/diceroll.o:C:\Users\Geneva\workspace\C++ Through Game Programming/diceroll.cpp:16: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/c___through_game_programming.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Geneva/workspace/C++ Through Game Programming'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Geneva/workspace/C++ Through Game Programming'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I have my environment variable PATH set right, when I installed the gbd I just extracted it to the normal C:\MinGW\bin so that I wouldn't have to do C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
Can anyone help out? If I can't figure this out I'm going to go back to coding in Java

Comment: You defined `main` twice in both main.cpp and diceroll.cpp.

Comment: Thank you @greatwolf! Thought I set up other stuff wrong lol sorry for the noobness

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message is clear: **You have defined multiple `main()` functions**